# How to show values when it is checked and submitted?

Tags: html, angularjs

How to show values only if it is checked. But do not show until submit button is clicked.

I have an example from  [doc Angular JS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) where when checked value will show.
How can I show these values when submit button is clicked show all checked values. and hide values if unchecked.

**html**

```
 Show: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" aria-label="Toggle ngShow"><br />
<div class="check-element animate-show-hide" ng-show="checked">
  I show up when your checkbox is checked.
</div>
```

**css**

```
.animate-show-hide.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate-show-hide.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.check-element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**Js**

```
it('should check ngShow', function() {
  var checkbox = element(by.model('checked'));
  var checkElem = element(by.css('.check-element'));

  expect(checkElem.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
  checkbox.click();
  expect(checkElem.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
});
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the form is submitted and checkbox is checked

```
 ng-show="yourFormName.$submitted && checked"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll implement it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another variable example:

HTML

```
Show: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" aria-label="Toggle ngShow"><br />
<div class="check-element animate-show-hide" ng-show="confirm">
   I show up when your checkbox is checked.
</div>
<button type="submit" ng-click="ShowDiv()" value="Show">Show</button>
```

Controller

```
$scope.ShowDiv = function () {
    if($scope.checked)
        $scope.confirm = true;
    else
        $scope.confirm = false;
};
```